# xcode cut last characters from string

Tags: xcode, string, nsstring, character, cut

I am working on a `Xcode` program and need to cut the last 5 characters from a string.

Does anybody know how to cut the last 5 characters from a `NSString`?

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? These might be multi-byte UTF-8 or single C type characters.

Answer (score 28):

just looked for it my self few minutes ago

```
NSString *str = @"1234567890";
NSString *newStr;

newStr = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-5];

NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
```

Comment: Or the inversion with `substringFromIndex`… Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late for this answer:

```
NSString *str = @"1234567890";
NSString *newStr;

newStr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(str.length -1, 1)];

NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
```

Although you provided a string of "1234567889" and the above code should work fine, however, in real life if it's a different string then please check to ensure that it's not empty before doing the above, otherwise, str.length would return -1 causing an error.

I hope this helps.

Kind Regards,
Heider Sati

Comment: you just take last character he want to remove last character